# Dymo LabelWriter Wireless on CUPS Print Server - Can't get it to work

Tags: cups, dymo

I am trying to add a Dymo LabelWriter Wireless to my CUPS server.

I have been using this ppd https://gist.github.com/vstath/0f5eab715cec427b86dcf9c47f397f04.

Also I am using socket://ip-address as an address for my printer inside CUPS, but nothing gets printed. CUPS says that the jobs are printed fine, but nothing happens.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the PPD no longer works. I reached out to their support department (sdkreply@newellco.com) and received the following reply:

The PPD file looks OK, besides the cupsFilter line. The LabelWriter Wireless requires a new driver since we have modified the communication protocol.

The new drivers haven’t been published yet. An update Linux SDK is on the task list, but the development hasn’t been scheduled yet.

We will post an update on https://developers.dymo.com/

Comment: Any news @Matthijs? It's almost 3 years later...?